# How to correct this variable

Tags: jquery

I have a variable issue below:

```
 function validation() {

                var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
    var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;    

    alertValidation= "";
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...

    $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {
    if (!this.value) {
        alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
    }
else if (currenttotal > $(this).val()){
    alertValidation += "\nYou have selected more answers than the required amount\n";
}

else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
    alertValidation += "\nYou have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
}
});
```

}

The problem is that for each row, it should look at the number entered in the .numberAnswerTxtRow textbox and see how many buttons (.answerBtnsOn.length) have been selected. If more buttons are selected than the figure entered in the textbox then, it should display alert that you have selected more answers than required. If vice versa it should do the same except display message stating you select less answers than required. The problem is that it doesn't recognise the figure entered in textbox and the amount of buttons selected for each row. This begs me to believe that I need to change the `var context` and `var currenttotal` to something else so it recognises the textbox and buttons selected for each row. What should I change these variables to?

Below is jquery code where the textbox and answers come from:

```
 function insertQuestion(form) {

            var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
    var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;  

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $noofanswers = $("<td class='noofanswers'></td>");
        var $answer = $("<td class='answer'></td>");

        $('.numberAnswerTxt', context).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $noofanswersText = '';

                $noofanswersText = $("<input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: block;' onkeyup='numberKeyUp(this)' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='getButtons()'>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val())    
            }
            $noofanswers.append($noofanswersText);
        });

        var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
        $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            if(i%7 == 0) {
                $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
                $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
            }
            var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
            $newBtn.appendTo($cell);
            i++;
        });

        $tr.append($answer);
        $tr.append($noofanswers);
        $tbody.append($tr);
    }
```

The rows are added into a table known as qandatbl:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="noofanswers">Number of Answers</th>
    <th class="answer">Answer</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is a little unspecific. Have you tried debugging your JS code? You can use Firebug or similar to do so. Just paste the jQuery selector in the Console and it will display the return value - using this approach you can see if the correct element is returned by the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks kind of complex and there is still some parts missing, so I can only guess... Why don't you have a look at what are you have in your variables. That should help you figure it out:

```
var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
console.log(context);
var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;  
console.log(context.find('.answerBtnsOn'));
```